# How can ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap preserve Unicode data?

Tags: openstreetmap, arcgis-editor-osm

Currently i am using [ArcGIS Editor for open Street map](http://esriosmeditor.codeplex.com/) for conversion of OSM file to file Geodatabase. But after conversion geometry is perfect but there is no Unicode data available in the attribute table. Am i missing some thing?

I am particularly interested in the house numbers and buildings names.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The forum on the official `esriosmeditor` site has this answer:

> **How can ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap preserve Unicode data?**
>
> Good question. The ArcGIS Editor for OSM absolutely supports the
>   Unicode data. However, it is not extracting all of the data into the
>   attribute table by default. To get at these additional values, run the
>   **OSM Attribute Selector** tool and select the values of interest. Then
>   you should be able to see these values in the table.

Comment: Do you have any clues about this Unicode question? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21636/khmer-unicode-script-in-arcgis-10

Comment: no, nope. no.  sorry.