# Khmer Unicode script in ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, internationalization

I am volunteering for the wonderful Cambodian urban NGO Sahmakum Teang Tnaut as a GIS and data analysis advisor for 10 months. My Khmer counterparts have found that ArcGIS does not support Khmer Unicode for producing Khmer script in maps, such as for labels and titles. Does anyone have any experience with getting Khmer Unicode to work? I, and my colleagues have it installed on my computer so can use it in other programs, just not ArcGIS it seems.

At the moment we have to use any of the Limon typefaces, which are much more cumbersome to write in as it takes up to three characters per Khmer character.

Comment: I found an ArcGIS Idea to provide support for Khmer Unicode at http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008ABjAAM so if you have not voted for it you may want to

Comment: I found this help page by Aruna: http://arunatechnology.com/2011/07/khmer-unicode-font-arcgis-1/ however the Khmer characters have unnecessary spaces between them, as others have commented on that page.

Answer (score 2):

I found an [**ArcGIS Idea**](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008ABjAAM) to provide support for Khmer Unicode so if you have not voted for it you may want to.